# Is there any issue running AMPPS and VVV Vagrant on the same host

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, vagrant, ampps

I am moving from AMPPS to vagrant and I need to have the two running at the same time so that I can move the old installations.

I installed vagrant ( I'm using [VVV apache edition](https://github.com/ericmann/vvv-apache) ) and got it working but when I launched AMPPS and tried to enter phpmyadmin I got an error ( exact same issue as on [this thread](http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=5447&title=) ... and fixed it using the last post on the thread ) ... but when I do vagrant up and go to vvv.dev and click the phpmyadmin link there I end up with a similar problem (  #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server ).

Does anyone know how to fix this ... or maybe it's not possible to run both together or I have to have the passwords in sync or something.

**Edit** Looking at this again I'm puzzled as to how vagrant could interfere with ampps in the first place. Surely being a virtual machine it means that the mysql running on the vagrant box is effectively running on a different computer?

Comment: @mevius is there some reason you want to remove the wordpress tag?

Comment: Yes, because this has nothing to do with WordPress at all.

Comment: VVV has nothing to do with WordPress? I have edited the title sorry I thought VVV was in there.

Comment: Do you have port forwarding set up on your VVV?